# Dynamic width float-left with ellipsis

Tags: css

I have a single-line fixed-width container `div` with two variable-width `span` inside. Any overflow of the first `span` should be hidden with an ellipsis. The second `span` floats on the right and should be shown in full. Please see [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba8djj8m/):

```
<div class='container'>
  <span class='left'>Long long variable stuff</span>
  <span class='right'>Changing stuff</span>
</div>
```

I want the first `span`'s width to dynamically adjust according to the width of the second `span` so that both `span` stay on the same line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox`, so with `flex: 1` on `.right`, `.left` will adjust its size and overflow will be hidden.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='left'>Long long variable stuff</span>
  <span class='right'>Changing stuff</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer does not include `float: right`. When I add it it does not float right. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is flexbox, there is no floats, you can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: Got a solution! The same effect can be done by setting `width: 100%` on `.left`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's any way for CSS to dynamically know the length of an element without javascript. If you're looking for a purely CSS solution you're going to need to give it some direction in order for it to know the widths you want. Visually, that might be a bit of a compromise for you, but it will allow you to ensure that everything is always on one line.

For the solution I'm about to propose to work you need to know **one** width of the two. In this case I'm going to say that you can make a best guess of the "changing stuff" on the right.

Your first problem is that spans are `inline` elements by default - not `inline-block`. In order to get the overflow text property to work, you need to use it with an `inline-block` or `block` element.

The next piece is to use `calc`. Calc excepts mixed measurements so you can subtract an exact pixel value off of a percent. This works really well for responsive layouts.

I've created an updated version of your plunker to illustrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/n19ddahb/5/